# end game actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

In my snake game I have the game in one movie clip and a game over movie clip. in my document class I would like to add game and when it ends set it to null, remove it and add the end game movie clip. what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I can see you are not reading fgdbe which tells people to put all code in the document class...

Comment: the purpose of my document class is to load the proper clips. my clips are a preloader, settings, the game, and the end game. the purpose of it is so i can make a clip null, remove it and when its reloaded it runs like it did the first time. otherwise when you go back to the game it would still be in the same state it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispatch an event from your game class that the document class can listen for (`Event.COMPLETE` seems fitting for this case). Then in the event handler, you can change your clips around.

Document Class code:

```
var game:Game = new Game();
game.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishGame);
addChild(game);

function finishGame(e:Event):void {
   removeChild(game);
   game = null;
   var end:GameOver = new GameOver();
   addChild(end);
}
```

Game Class code:

```
//when game is complete:
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```